# Error while installing Dynamic Code Evolution VM (DCE) with Java 8

Tags: java, ubuntu, hotswap, dce, hotswapagent

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit) with Java 8. I am facing following error while installing Dynamic Code Evolution VM (DCE) with Java 8.

> **Could not find data/64/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so in jar-file.**

[image]

I have tried to put amd64 libraries in classpath as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/
```

It didn't work.

Also, I created `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` file and added following lines to it:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

And then executed following command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

It didn't work either. Kindly share some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Used latest executable from forked Project of DCEVM Project on [GitHub](http://dcevm.github.io/). It worked!